# JS - factory pattern overwrites private vars when stored in memory

Tags: javascript, factory-pattern

so i'm still pretty new to js and i wanted to get into the more advanced stuff but i have this problem with the factory pattern, here's the basic code :

```
(function () {

    var objs = [];

    function createObj(name) {

        var thename = name;

        return {
            publicsaythename : function () {
                console.log(thename);   
            }
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var theObj = createObj("thename" + i);
        theObj.publicsaythename();

        objs.push(theObj);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
        theObj.publicsaythename();
    }

})();
```

the first series of console.log calls outputs what i expect:

```
thename0
thename1 
thename2 
thename3 
thename4
```

The second series of console.logs outputs the last object i created 5 times.

```
 5 x thename4
```

Am i doing something wrong? or is this expected?

also if it is expected. how do you solve the problem of being able to store the objects you create for later use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only store ONE object reference in the `theObj` variable, so the output is as expected.

I think this is what you intended to do in the second loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
     objs[i].publicsaythename();
}
```

So there's nothing wrong with how you store the objects. I guess you just made a mistake using them. :-)

Comment: ahh, *facepalm*.... but how is theObj object available in the second loop if its only scoped into the first for loop?

Comment: It is not scoped to the first loop. There are no *block scopes* in javascript, only *function scopes* (closures). Therefore `theObj` is declared in the scope of your anonymous function and available to the second loop.

Comment: I see. learning something new everyday. Thanks for your help!